# Viewstate still coming on page source

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, viewstate

In the page directive of my page I have set EnableViewState="false". But I am still seeing some viewstate on my page source with this field

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/...................................
```

How can I remove the view state completely. I am using .NET 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is [Control State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1whwt1k7.aspx). It cannot be turned off.

Answer (score 0):

try using `ViewStateMode` property , as you are using .net 4

```
ViewStateMode="Disabled"
```

check for these links

1. [Viewstate controling asp.net 4.0](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/81489/ViewState-Control-in-ASP-NET-4-0)

Comment: I'm afraid this won't remove viewstate completely... Have you tried it? When I was trying it last time, there was still some info passed through anyway and there was no easy way of overriding this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, it's a feature of webforms. If you don't like this, use MVC instead.

Comment: Then what is this EnableViewState="false" for?

Comment: @RockySingh, to disable some of the webforms functionality, but as far as I know, there's still some info that needs to be passed for webforms. By the way, why is this an issue for you? You know, viewstate is good as a kind of a security layer as well to prevent CSRF and similar nasty stuff. If your website is slow, the problem is 10000% somewhere else and not in this one line of code. Learn to use the viewstate properly and you'll be glad to have it.